# Page breaks in html don't appear when embedded in a docx file with docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I'm outputting a Word (docx) file using docx4j, and the page breaks aren't appearing in the document.
I'm using:

```
hr {page-break-after: always}
```

for the css, but it isn't rendering as a page break in the Word document.

What html or css should I be using to get an html page break to transfer over to the docx file?

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this was possible?

Comment: @nbrooks I've sort of given up on using docx4j, but this is what I see in my code now:  `Br objBr = new Br();
  objBr.setType(STBrType.PAGE);  wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(objBr);`

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me,  try to use this tag:

> > `<br style=\"page-break-after: always; clear:both;\"></br>`

All other tag not worked with style css.

Answer (score 1):

**Works with heading tags or paragraph tags (h1, h2, p):**

I used this css style with h1 tags in my html content and  successfully got the page-breaks applying after the heading in my exported word document:

```
String pageBreakMarker = "<h1 style=\"page-break-after: always;\"></h1>";
```

I think this is not working with html break tags has to do with how docx4j treats html break tags.

Even looking at the getting started sample on github, I only see the 'page-break-after' or 'page-break-before' being used with only html paragraph tags (p)

See link to Docx4j getting started guide on github below:

- [Docx4j Getting Started](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html)

**Does not work with html break tags:**

Using docx4, I can confirm I the "page-break-after" or "page-break-before" does not work when trying to create page breaks in word docs from  html content with break tags (hr):

```
<br style=\"page-break-after: always; clear:both;\"></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line before heading tags or paragraph tags (h1, h2, p) :

```
<p style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0mm; page-break-before: always">
```

When i open it in OpenOffice writer, it breaks the page.